# Who are these characters shown in post credit scene of Episode 4 of Loki?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, loki-2021

In *Loki*, Season 1 Episode 4 - During the post-credit scene, Loki is greeted by a couple of characters after he wakes up. Who are they?

> [image: 3 characters look down to the character in on the floor with a ruined city in the background]

Comment: oh crap, there are post-credit scenes, I did not know...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are Loki Variants, as seen from the credits we have:

#### [Classic Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Classic_Loki)

This is a variant of Loki based on Loki from his first Modern Age appearance in *Journey into Mystery Vol. 1* Issue 85.

[image: Loki as he appears in the comics in the green spandex with gold/yellow highlights and the classic horned helmet]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### [Kid Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Kid_Loki)

This is a variant of Loki based on Kid Loki from the comics whose first appearance was in *Thor Vol. 1* Issue 617.

[image: Thor transforms the hidden Loki into Kid Loki using Mjolnir]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### [Boastful Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Boastful_Loki)

As far as I can tell Boastful Loki isn't based on any one character, it's possible it's a variation on Loki, God of Heroism and Truth, from *Loki: Agent of Asgard* Issue 9 but no clear indication.

[image: Loki being worthy to wield Mjolnir charges at Thor who no longer can]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

However, this variant does look quite like the one we see in a *Thor: The Dark World* [deleted scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_iOTgLoru0) where Loki projects a vision of what it would be like if he was crowned. It's possible this Loki ties closer into Thor and actually ruled for a while. Note the Loki in the deleted scene can also wield Mjolnir.

[image: Loki in an outfit like Thor's with a fur trim looks out over his new kingdom]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### [Alligator Loki](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Alligator_Loki)

As far as I can tell this variant Loki is a new creation and not based on anything else from the comics. It's possible it is just a normal Loki that got stuck in transformation like when the main Loki transformed into a snake to scare Thor.

> **Thor:** Yes, me too. On many, many occasions. There was one time when we were children, he transformed himself into a snake, and he knows that I love snakes. So, I went to pick up the snake to admire it and he transformed back into himself and he was like, "Yeah, it's me!" And he stabbed me. We were eight at the time.
>
> <sub>*Thor: Ragnarok*</sub>

Comment: Crocodile Loki is a little reminiscent of Throg (frog Thor) from the comics. Could he be... Croki?

Comment: Croki would be ADORABLE!!!

Comment: Also, is Classic Loki meant to be the Loki from the comics? If that's the case, doesn't that technically make Spider-Man: Into the Spider-Verse MCU canon?

Comment: @Gothamite24 I guess we'll find out more in the next episode. However, it's unlikely, they're probably just based off of them for some Easter eggs for fans to pick up on.

Comment: Hammer-guy looks like Thor, Loki, and Heimdall all got into that machine from *The Fly* at the same time.  Come to think of it, Jeff Goldblum *was* a major character in a Thor movie, maybe there's some cross-pollination going on here...

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot-Fingers crossed, there have already been teases in the past that Earth-616 is part of the MCU Multiverse

Answer (score 11):

I can't identify the hammer guy but the other two of them seems Loki variants: [Kid Loki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Loki_Laufeyson_(Kid_Loki)_(Earth-616)) and "first appearance" Loki by Jack Kirby from [*Journey into Mystery* #85](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Journey_into_Mystery_Vol_1_85).

[image: Kid Loki]

[image: Journey into Mystery] [image: Original Loki]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Note: The second adult Loki image does not belong to #85 but a later issue.

In some web pages, like [this one](http://screenrant.com/loki-show-variants-versions-mcu-prediction) supplied by @AncientSwordRage, it's said that hammer guy may be Loki, God of Heroism and Thruth, as seen in *Loki: Agent of Asgard* #9.

[image: Loki: Agent of Asgard]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Is the missing Loki one of these? https://screenrant.com/loki-show-variants-versions-mcu-prediction/

Comment: One of them is played by this [actor](https://santa-clarita-diet.fandom.com/wiki/Loki_Hayes).

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Oh, wow, so that is a nice little meta-joke for the fans.  Now I'm wondering if they're going to connect it to *[The Mask](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110475/)* (or [its horrible sequel](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0362165/)) somehow...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I think they're all connected some how, but I don't know how exactly - so maybe.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Had to check that the old guy is *not* [Alan Cumming](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001086/), who played Loki in *Son of the Mask*.  Almost think they should've done that, except nobody wants to be reminded that movie exists...